# Calling NT function on pre-NT system

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, dll

So I don't do a lot of Win32 calls, but recently I have had to use the [`GetFileTime()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724320(VS.85).aspx) and [`SetFileTime()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724933(VS.85).aspx) functions. Now although Win98 and below are not officially supported in my program people do use it there anyway, and I try to keep it as usable as possible. I was just wondering what will happen as those functions do not exist in pre-NT systems, will they receive an error message of some sort for example because in that case I will add in an OS check? Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you call the functions directly, then your program will not load on Win98.

What you can do is use `LoadLibrary()` / `GetProcAddress()` to get a pointer to `GetFileTime()` / `SetFileTime()`. On Win98 this will fail, giving you a null pointer which you can test for and ignore. On 2000 and later you will get a pointer which you can then use.

It's a pain, but it's the only solution I know of.

Here is an example of getting the UpdateLayeredWindow function if it exists:

```
typedef BOOL (WINAPI* UpdateLayeredWinFunc) (HWND, HDC, POINT*, SIZE*, HDC, POINT*, COLORREF, BLENDFUNCTION*, DWORD);

UpdateLayeredWinFunc updateLayeredWindow = 0;
HMODULE user32Mod = GetModuleHandle (_T("user32.dll"));
updateLayeredWindow = (UpdateLayeredWinFunc) GetProcAddress (user32Mod, "UpdateLayeredWindow");
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you get an error message along the lines of "The procedure entry point (name) could not be located in (dll)", similar th the one shown:

[example http://img266.imageshack.us/img266/3762/error2pm1.png](http://img266.imageshack.us/img266/3762/error2pm1.png)

Answer (score 0):

You could call `FindFirstFile()` instead of `GetFileTime()`. I wouldn't know an alternative for `SetFileTime()`, though.

Comment: From the research I have done it seems that there isn't one, thanks though!